# Как выявить недостающие npm-пакеты в package.json?

Tags: npm

Делаем проект на Angular 2. Пользуемся для контроля версий Git. Пушим рабочие файлы проекта в ветку master. Далее один из разработчиков делает клон репо, выполняем команду npm install. В итоге не можем сбилдить проект - такое чувство, что не закачиваются все пакеты npm проекта, то есть что-то не прописано в конфиге проекта, но пакеты есть. 
Привожу часть лога билда клонированного репо

```
 ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:22:31
TS1005: ',' expected.
 ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:24:32
TS1005: ',' expected.
 ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/handlebars/index.d.ts:99:40
  TS1005: ',' expected.
 ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes  /async_pipe.d.ts:44:38
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
 ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot  /compiler.d.ts:32:38
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

Как устранить странную проблему? Ведь исходный код билдится, а клон исходных текстов нет. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: может пакеты все-таки закачиваются, но зависимости устарели?

Comment: Надо метки поправить, тут больше вопрос по `npm`. Попробуйте `npm list` - выведет список всех установленных пакетов.

Comment: Метка git тут лишняя... разве что вы хотите найти коммит, поломавший сборку и посмотреть, что в нём было такого.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать npm@5 или yarn. Они умеют создавать специальные lock файлы, которые сохраняют строго ту версию пакета, которую вы установили. Все другие разрабы гарантированно установят эту же версию.